# MVC How to change a buttons text on submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to create a simple MVC 4 app with a few buttons that when clicked adds one to their text value.  The problem is when I use < input > buttons I can't change the text value when I submit the form and when I use < button > then there is nothing passed to the action.

I have a simple SQL Database that the controller hits which is where the initial ViewData values are coming from and how it's storing the buttons current value.

Also I'm currently trying to do this with multiple forms but if it is possible with one form then that would be ideal.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddOne", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "btn-tc-top"}, new { @class = "rectangle-top" }))
{   
     <input type="submit" class="button" name="button" id="btn-tc-top" value="@ViewData["ct-t"]"/>
}
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddOne", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "btn-tc-bottom"}, new { @class = "rectangle-bottom" }))
{   
      <button type="submit" class="button" name="button" id="btn-tc-bottom">@ViewData["ct-b"]</button>
}
```

Comment: you want to set the text of button from your server (returned from action method ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subscribe to the `OnSuccess` handler:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddOne", "Home", new { id = "btn-tc-top" }, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "addSuccess" }, new { @class = "rectangle-top" }))
{   
    <input id="btn-tc-top" class="button" type="submit" name="button" value="@ViewData["ct-t"]" />
}
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddOne", "Home", new { id = "btn-tc-bottom" }, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "addSuccess" }, new { @class = "rectangle-bottom" }))
{   
    <input id="btn-tc-bottom" class="button" type="submit" name="button" value="@ViewData["ct-b"]" />
}
```

which could be defined like this:

```
function addSuccess(result) {
    $('#' + result.id).val(result.text);
}
```

and the controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["ct-t"] = "1";
        ViewData["ct-b"] = "2";
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddOne(string id, int button)
    {
        return Json(new { id = id, text = button + 1 });
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get that too work.  I really don't know javascript very well but how is the script adding a parameter to the AddOne ActionResult?

Comment: There are 2 parameters: `id` and `button`. The `id` is passed as a routeValue in the `Ajax.BeginForm` (see `new { id = "btn-tc-top" }`) and the button parameter is the name of the button so its value is automatically submitted. In order for Ajax.* helpers to work make sure that you have included both `jQuery.js` and `jQuery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` scripts (in that order) to your page. If you are using bundles simply include `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` and `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")`.